# app window detect whether it is in the background in FMX Delphi Windows and Macintosh

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

My Delphi 11 FMX project has multiple document windows.

How can I detect in code whether or not the window is in the background? (Windows and Macintosh)

Comment: I've resorted to storing a flag fWindowIsInBackground that gets set in FormActivate() and FormDeactivate() but there must be a more straightforward way to tell if the window is in the background.

Comment: At least on Windows, the `Active:boolean` property indicates whether the form has focus.

Comment: @TomBrunberg The Active property is apparently not updated until after FormDeactivate() is completed. That could be be design.

Comment: Yes Mike, I noticed the same, but did not investigate closer, yet. I'll take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Active: Boolean` property indicates whether the form has focus.

Note, however:

1. In procedure `TCommonCustomForm.Activate;` the `Active` property is set `True` **before** `OnActivate` is called.
2. In procedure `TCommonCustomForm.Deactivate;` the `Active` property is set `False` **after** `OnDeactivate` is called.

Therefore, referring to the `Active` property *in these events (`OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate`)* might be error prone. OTOH, the events already tell what the state will be after exit.

**Outside of these** events the `Active` property correctly indicate the actual state.